# How to organize a relatively large Flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I'm building my first Flask app and I can't figure out a good, clean Pythonic way of organizing my application.
I don't want to have everything in a single .py file as in their example.
I would like to have each part of my app in a separate module.
What would be a good way to organize things?

Comment: I quite like the layout explained here: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/

Comment: There they are using circular imports which i would like to avoid.

Comment: True, but I don't think it's avoidable if you want to use the app.route decorator.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I have created a Flask boilerplate project called "[Fbone](https://github.com/imwilsonxu/fbone)", please feel free to check it out and fork :)

Fbone (Flask bone) is a Flask (Python microframework) template/bootstrap/boilerplate application.

Overview

- Well designed for big project using blueprint.
- Integrate with hottest frontend framework: jQuery / html5boilerplate / bootstrap.
- Backed by the famous SQLalchemy.
- Implement tricky "remember me" by flask-login.
- Handle web forms by flask-wtform.
- Unit testing with flask-testing and nose.
- Easily deploy via fabric and mod_wsgi (example included).
- i18n by flask-babel

btw, I just found this [wiki](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/wiki/Large-app-how-to) on building a large project with Flask useful, pls check it!

Comment: Before you run 'fab d' as detailed in the README, you need to activate your virtual environment with 'source env/bin/activate'

Comment: Foundation will be better than bootstrap, huh?

Comment: @imwilsonxu I couldn't tell where you put multiple models.  Do you put models in different files like a php framework does?

Comment: (fbone)MacBook-Pro-de-Pyderman:flask-boilerplate Pyderman$ `fab setup`

`Warning: Command(s) not found:
    setup`

Comment: @imwilsonxu Can the api part in the fbone project be used by mobile apps? So that the application based on the fbone project can be accessed from web and by mobile native clients?

Answer (score 21):

Flask 0.7 implements [Blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/blueprints/). They are great for using the `route` decorator without importing the main application object.

Comment: How is a blueprint different than a module?

Comment: Technically, a blueprint is an instance of the Blueprint class. They can span one or more modules, or several blueprints can coexist in the same module. There is some magic behind the scenes to figure out a blueprint's module or package, to find its `templates` and `static` folders.

Comment: I've integrate blueprints in my flask bone project, see my answer pls.

Answer (score 21):

**Make sure to read** Matt Wright's [***wonderful* post**](http://mattupstate.com/blog/how-i-structure-my-flask-applications/) on the subject.

The post features:

1. A description of a structure for large flask projects
2. [An example application on Github](https://github.com/mattupstate/overholt)
3. **A description of best design practices in general** when it comes to large web apps, like the MVC pattern, App factories, Services and Data Migration to name a few (most interesting feature IMHO).

Comment: A great explanation with examples.

Answer (score 13):

I'm working on a (by my standards) big Flask project (5000 lines of Python code and it's only half-finished). The customer wants the project to be modular, so I took this apporach:

My folder structure looks like this:

```
├── __init__.py
├── modules.yml
├── config
├── controllers
│   └── ...
├── lib: Common functions I use often
│   └── ...
├── models
│   └── ...
├── static: All static files
│   ├── css
│   ├── img
│   └── js
└── templates: Jinja2 templates
    └── ...
```

In `modules.yml` I define my modules including name and URL. This way the customer is able to enable/disable modules without touching a single Python file. In addition, I generate the menus based on the modules list. By convention every module has it its own Python-module in `controllers/` that will load its `model` from `models/`. Every controller defines a `Blueprint` stored as the controller's name. E.g. for a `user` module, I have in `controllers/user.py`:

```py
# Module name is 'user', thus save Blueprint as 'user' variable
user = Blueprint('user', __name__)

@user.route('/user/')
def index():
    pass
```

This way, I can read the `modules.yml` in my `__init__.py` and load and register all enabled modules dynamically:

```py
# Import modules
for module in modules:

    # Get module name from 'url' setting, exculde leading slash
    modname = module['url'][1:]

    try:
        # from project.controllers.<modname> import <modname>
        mod = __import__(
            'project.controllers.' + modname, None, None, modname
        )
    except Exception as e:
        # Log exceptions here
        # [...]

    mod = getattr(mod, modname)  # Get blueprint from module
    app.register_blueprint(mod, url_prefix=module['url'])
```

I hope, this can be some inspiration for you :)

Comment: where do you put your test files?

Comment: The structure described above is actually a subdirectory with the project name (`project_name/`). There also is a `tests/` folder and a `scripts/` folder (for executable scripts). For `tests/` it would be clever to use the same structure as in the answer: `tests/models/` for model tests, `tests/controllers/` for controller tests, you name it. That would require some overhead for maintaining the structure but would make it very simple to find the files you need.

Answer (score 7):

I worked on a social network built on top of Flask. The special thing about my project was that the server is purely serving API endpoints and the frontend is a one-page Backbone app. The Flask structure I took is the following:

`├── app
    │   ├── api

    │   │   ├── auth.py
    │   │   └── ...
    │   ├── app.py
    │   ├── common
    │   │   ├── constants.py
    │   │   ├── helpers.py
    │   │   ├── response.py
    │   │   └── ...
    │   ├── config.py
    │   ├── extensions.py
    │   ├── frontend
    │   │   └── controllers.py
    │   ├── static
    │   │   └── ...
    │   ├── templates
    │   │   ├── app.html
    │   │   └── ...
    │   └── users
    │       ├── UserConstants.py
    │       ├── UserForms.py
    │       ├── UserHelpers.py
    │       ├── UserModels.py
    │       └── __init__.py
    ├── alembic
    |   ├── version
    │   └── ...
    ├── tests
    │   └── ...`

You can read the more in-depth post I wrote on the topic [here](http://blog.sampingchuang.com/structure-a-large-flask-api-backend-app/). I found it to be much more intuitive to separate different functional areas to its own folder.

I worked on the code a while ago and open sourced it completely! You can check it out [on github](https://github.com/spchuang/DoubleDibz-tutorial/tree/master/FINAL).

Comment: Thanks. Looks nice.

Answer (score 3):

I have created a Flask app **yapper** from scratch and integrated it with gulp for both frontend and backend development.
It is a simple blog engine but can be easily modified for developing according to requirements. It is well structured using Blueprints.

Checkout the project page [yapper](https://github.com/brijeshb42/yapper)