# How do I modulate a Python web application?

Tags: python, mongodb, amazon-web-services, flask

Lets assume I am using Flask and MongoDB and host everthing on AWS and I am building a Twitter clone. I have one small instance for front-end, one large instance for back-end and one database instance.

So can someone please explain the idea to have 'separate' module on two different servers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The question/the problem is? Should we split your code without knowing it?

Comment: The [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/) offers some hints.

Comment: What i meant is that i am trying to figure out how an application being spread out on multiple servers. @esaelPsnoroMoN  Please do not be so condescending. I am a noob and trying to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at this project on github: https://github.com/givp/Flask-MongoDB-Project

This similar SO question: [How to organize a relatively large Flask application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9395587/how-to-organize-a-relatively-large-flask-application)

And this wiki page: https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/wiki/Large-app-how-to